# dot product vs inner product?

Tags: inner-products

For $V_n$ where $x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)$,
the dot product is defined by $x_1y_1+x_2y_2+ \cdots+x_ny_n$.

In Apostol's calculs vol 2

It says that if $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ are any two vectors in $V_2$, define $(x \cdot y)$ by the formula

$(x \cdot y)= 2x_1y_1+x_1y_2+x_2y_1+x_2y_2$

Why is that?

Is there difference between dot and inner product?

I thought that following the dot product, $(x \cdot y)$ should be $x_1y_1+x_2y_2$.

Comment: The dot product is another name for an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and typically refers to the one you mentioned first. Inner products are more general but share many of the same properties with the usual dot  product.

Answer (score 1):

An inner product is defined on any real or complex vector space by having three properties, the details are well listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space
The dot product between two real vectors in a real vector space satisfies all of these properties, so it is AN inner product, but there are others.  Also note things get funkier when you shift your field to the complex numbers